# Zend framework exception handling: Exception Details

Tags: exception, zend-framework, zend-framework2

We are working with the ZF2 exception handling and logging all the exceptions into a log file.
We are not getting the exact details of the file and line number using the `$e->getFile() and $e->getLine()` methods.

Is there any other approach to get the exact file/controller/action/model and line number?
We are getting the file as DBAdapter.php instead of exact model name.

Below is the code sample, where am trying to get the exact trace of the error file and line of the error occurrence. 
Am using a controller plugin from which all the exceptions will be logged to error log file.

```
    Public function indexAction(){
            try{
                $model = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Model\SomeModel');
                $model ->wrongMethod()->toArray(); //worngMethod i.e method does not exists in model.
            }catch(\Exception $e){
                return $this->LibraryPlugin()->showExceptionMessage($e, $this);
            }
        }

    //LibraryPlugin – Controller Plugin
        public function showExceptionMessage(\Exception $e, $current_obj)
        {
            //$e -> Exception Detials
            $e->getMessage ->C:\xampp\htdocs\project\config\package\ZF2\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php
            $e->getLine()   -> 482
        }



 - Exception Object
[message:protected] => Invalid method (wrongMethod) called, caught by Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway::__call()
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\project\config\package\ZF2\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php
    [line:protected] => 482

I can see within trace which has the exact details, but does not remain at the same index for all kinds of exceptions ie.(  
InvalidArgumentException -> $e->getTrace()[0]  
PDOException -> $e->getTrace()[2]  
InvalidQueryException-> $e->getTrace()[3]  
ServiceNotCreatedException -> $e->getTrace()[5]  
).  
Is there a way to get the exact error file name with line number, without explicitly unpacking and getting the details from trace object.  
Ex : getFile()-> SomeController.php, getLine()-> line in IndexController where the invalid method is being called.

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Show us code how do you handle these exceptions

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you want to trace back and get the chain of exceptions rather than just the last one in the chain.

such as:

```
$exception = $exception->getPrevious(); // grab previous exception.
```

You could grab all previous exceptions with something like this:

```
while ($exception instanceof \Exception) {
    $exceptions .= sprintf("Exception: %s\nTrace:\n%s\n", $exception->getMessage(), $exception->getTraceAsString());
    $exception   = $exception->getPrevious();
}
```